# Debugging kernel hang because of IOCTL calls

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, ioctl

I am trying to make a kernel module which is working on 2.6.32 kernel to work on 3.6 kernel. We use IOCTL calls to update structures in Linux Kernel Module. These calls are working fine in 2.6.32 kernel.

When I try the same in 3.6 kernel I am facing kernel hang whenever ioctl calls are made from user-space application. Its a socket based interface not a file based interface hence we use the ioctl under struct proto_ops.

How can I debug this scenario as there is no core dump generated. To copy data from userspace I am using copy_from_user command.

Any pointers for debugging this scenario would be very helpful

Comment: Is there anything special in the system log after the system hangs? A hang may be a sign of a kernel oops or panic among other things. Have you tried to output the system log via a serial console to get it reliably even if the kernel crashes? Also, if you can post the relevant portions of the code here, this could help to find out what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

ioctl() is one of the remaining parts of the kernel which runs under the Big Kernel Lock (BKL). In the past, the usage of the BKL has made it possible for long-running ioctl() methods to create long latencies for unrelated processes.

Follows an explanation of the patch that introduced unlocked_ioctl and compat_ioctl into 2.6.11. The removal of the ioctl field happened a lot later, in 2.6.36.

Explanation: When ioctl was executed, it took the [Big Kernel Lock (BKL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_lock), so nothing else could execute at the same time. This is very bad on a multiprocessor machine, so there was a big effort to get rid of the BKL. First, unlocked_ioctl was introduced. It lets each driver writer choose what lock to use instead. This can be difficult, so there was a period of transition during which old drivers still worked (using ioctl) but new drivers could use the improved interface (unlocked_ioctl). Eventually all drivers were converted and ioctl could be removed.

compat_ioctl is actually unrelated, even though it was added at the same time. Its purpose is to allow 32-bit userland programs to make ioctl calls on a 64-bit kernel. The meaning of the last argument to ioctl depends on the driver, so there is no way to do a driver-independent conversion.

Reference: The [new way of ioctl()](https://lwn.net/Articles/119652/) by [Jonathan Corbet](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

Comment: so... that article is from 2005, is that still true? There's an unlocked_ioctl in file_operations, but there is no unlocked_ioctl in block_device_operations.